# Edge check in cartesian coordinate system

Tags: ruby

I have a cartesian plane with fixed dimensions

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 10, 20
```

I want to determine if a point represented as an ordered pair is an edge or a corner of that plane. For example, `[0, 0]` and `[9, 19]` are corners; `[0, 5]` and `[6, 19]` are edges.

This is my code:

```
# max allowable x and y coordinates
MAXX = WIDTH - 1
MAXY = HEIGHT - 1

# is this coordinate at the corner of the plane?
def corner?(*coords)
  coords.uniq == [0]     || # lower-left corner
  coords == [MAXX, MAXY] || # upper-right corner
  coords == [MAXX, 0]    || # lower-right corner
  coords == [0, MAXY]       # upper-left corner
end

# is this coordinate at the edge of the plane?
def edge?(*coords)
  return (
    (
      coords.include?(0)  || # if x or y coordinate is at
      coords[0] == MAXX  || # its min or max, the coordinate
      coords[1] == MAXY     # is an edge coordinate
    ) && 
    !corner?(coords) # it's not an edge if it's a corner
  )
end
```

It gives these results, which I would expect:

```
corner?(0, 0) #=> true
corner?(0, 5) #=> false
edge?(0, 5)   #=> true
corner?(5, 5) #=> false
edge?(5, 5)   #=> false
```

However, while I expect the following:

```
edge?(0, 0) #=> true
```

it gives

```
edge?(0, 0)   #=> false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in your `edge?` method, you are calling:

```
def edge?(*coords)
  #...
  !corner?(coords)
end
```

in which `coords` is a single `Array`, i.e, you are calling `corner?([0, 0])`, not `corner?(0, 0)`. Instead, expand the argument like this:

```
def edge?(*coords)
  #...
  !corner?(*coords)
end
```